# How to send params in Select2 ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I making an ajax call in select2 but I am not sure on how to send my params int it. I am doing a GET where I need to send an x_id to backend to fetch an array of y_id and y_name. I have seen many post where they talked about POST method and querying. Below code is an example, but how would I do my task in terms of a GET call.

```
$(".js-example").select2({
ajax: {
  url: $element.data("url"),
  type: "POST",
  quietMillis: 100,
  data: function (term, page) {
    return {
      query: term,
      page: page,
      pageLimit: 25
    };
  },
  results: function (data, page) {
    return data;
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With a `GET` request you can append it to the URL within the query string. When using `jQuery` `AJAX` this is achieved by changing the type parameter to `GET` and using the `data` property. When jQuery sends the request it will append the querystring with key value pairs from data parameter.

```
$(".js-example").select2({
ajax: {
  url: $element.data("url"),
  type: "GET",
  quietMillis: 100,
  data: function (term, page) {
    return {
      query: term,
      page: page,
      pageLimit: 25,
      <x_id>: x_id
    };
  },
  results: function (data, page) {
    return data;
  }
}
}
```